# How does C struct ignore inner order, for a compiler?

Tags: c, struct

For example, we have two struct:

```
struct type1 {
    int  t;
    char c;
};

struct type2 {
    char c;
    int  t;
};
```

In which stage can a C compiler ignore the difference in order and settle them as a same struct? And how?

Comment: Note: there are two semicolons missing from your struct definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In which stage can a C compiler ignore the difference in order and
>   settle them as a same struct? And how?

Compiler does not ignore the order in which the struct members are declared. In fact, a structure guarantees that the members are laid out in memory in the same order they are declared in, notwithstanding the padding bits which are inserted when necessary for the struct alignment. Therefore, the compiler will always treat `struct type1` and `struct type2` as different types.

Comment: I just wanted to add, the reason the answer is "never" is because developers may be writing their own APIs that accept these structs, and not necessarily in C. They therefore *need* a universal way of knowing the order and offsets of the fields, and the struct definition in the .h file is perfect for that.